# Can't delete file within folder in C

Tags: c

Im making a txt editor in the terminal, one of it's features is to edit a specific line.
To do so,

I am creating a new temporary txt file,
deleting the old/original one
and renaming the temporary one to the original.

Here's the code:

```
FileLineEdit(char filename[20], int line, char newline[1000]){

    FILE * fp;
    FILE * fptmp;

    char buffer[1000];
    int count;

    int ret;


    fp  = fopen(filename, "r");
    fptmp = fopen("tmp/replace.txt", "w");

    if (fp == NULL || fptmp == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nErro!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    count = 0;
    while ((fgets(buffer, 1000, fp)) != NULL)
    {
        count++;

        if (count == line)
            fputs(newline, fptmp);
        else
            fputs(buffer, fptmp);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fptmp);

    //strcat(fullpath, filename);
    //printf("%s", fullpath);

   ret = remove(filename);

   if(ret == 0) {
      printf("File deleted successfully");
   } else {
      printf("Error: unable to delete the file");
   }

    rename("tmp/replace.txt", "tmp/a.txt");

    getch();

}
```

The output is constantly:
`Error: unable to delete the file`

*btw once I try this outside the "tmp/" folder it works just fine*

Comment: Why did you comment out the use of `fullpath`?

Comment: did you mean to use /tmp ?

Comment: What happens if the user runs two or more copies of this program concurrently? You need to use temporary, unique filenames (not /tmp/replace.txt) if you're going to do this properly.

Comment: `tmp/filename` is not the same as `/tmp/filename` unless your current directory happens to be the root directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/tmp` folder has the sticky bit (`s`) set, and that means, that anyone can read and create/modify files in it, but only its owner (root) can remove them.

So, if is what you want your program to do, you should do it in some directory other than `/tmp`

Also, as jarmod pointed out, you shouldn't have a hardcoded filename for your temporary filename. You should use [tmpfile](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/tmpfile/) or [tmpnam](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/tmpnam/) for this purpose:
Instead of:

```
fptmp = fopen("tmp/replace.txt", "w");
```

Write:

```
fptmp = tmpfile();
```

The file will be automatically deleted when the file stream is closed.

(You can read a more about the `/tmp` dir [here](https://www.ubuntupit.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-linux-tmp-directory/))

Comment: The file's owner can delete it (not just root).

Comment: Oh, right. Maybe it's because of the missing starting slash?

Comment: The sticky bit was probably the problem; maybe he was trying to edit someone else's files